# Python Opencv2 Camera with Start Flashlight, Stop Flashlight, Click Picture, Start Video Recording, Stop Video Recording buttons

Tags: python, image, opencv, video, camera

I am trying to build a camera application with PyQT and OpenCV2. So far I am successful in making buttons to click picture, start recording, stop recording.
However managing the Flash on/off is still out of reach. 
Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

OS : Ubuntu
Language : Python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You describe with *"click picture, start recording, stop recording"* default imaging behavior of cameras. Those buttons work on most cams using opencv (/pyqt) but beyond is SDK manufacturer specific.

If you can't figure it out with your camera post product name, type, version into your question.

For example... FLIR has a vast amount of SDK libraries with python wrappers [here](https://www.google.nl/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjI2rnyg7LZAhUP_aQKHfImDGQQFggnMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.ptgrey.com%2Fflycapture-sdk&usg=AOvVaw3pngaK411m5mmToznCdWg7). A crude example via Flea2 cam is [here](https://www.ptgrey.com/Downloads/BySKU?family=Flea2&sku=FL2-20S4M-C). If installed you can test the basics with some example scripts. And if you dig deep enough you'll hit "Nokia" related image libraries... written for cams on phones... Nostalgia <3

Hence, as `karlphilip` mentioned in his post... the libraries are fingerprinted towards series of cameras from a camera manufacturer and are likely not fitted for cams from other manufacturers. But.. when you import lib from more than one manufacturer you can combine it in your python scripts.. obviously.

Comment: Just the answer I was looking for. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming there is a real camera attached to your computer, you will need to look into the camera driver to accomplish that. This process is a unique to your camera model and manufacturer.

If you are lucky, you might even be able to find a 3rd party library that does exactly that (for your particular camera) and offers a module to do it more easily in Python.

Good luck!

Comment: If it's not clear from the answer, PyQT and OpenCV can't help you with that feature.

Comment: Thanks a ton for your help.