# No image from the camera using cv2.VideoCapture

Tags: python, opencv

I use WebCam(Genius FaceCam 1020),Python(3.6.4), OpenCV(3.4.0.12), and Opencv documentation code, this one:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while(True):
    # Capture frame-by-frame
    ret, frame = cap.read()

    # Our operations on the frame come here
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    # Display the resulting frame
    cv2.imshow('frame',gray)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

# When everything done, release the capture
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Runs without errors, but the image does not appear in the window. The indicator on the camera lights up.
I have tried copy opencv_ffmpeg.dll, Rename the opencv_ffmpeg.dll in this manner:

For OpenCV version X.Y.Z

```
opencv_ffmpeg.dll ==> opencv_ffmpegXYZ.dll
```

For 64-bit OpenCV version X.Y.Z

```
opencv_ffmpeg.dll ==> opencv_ffmpegXYZ_64.dll
```

Namely `opencv_ffmpeg34012.dll` and `opencv_ffmpeg34012_64.dll`. But it does not help.

Comment: have you tried using `VideoCapture(n)` with a different index n? `0` represents the default device. e.g. my internal notebook cam is `0` and my external one is `1`, even tough I have set the external one as default.

Comment: @Skandix when I used different index 1, I get error
Like this 
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (scn == 3 || scn == 4) in cv::cvtColor, file C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\color.cpp, line 11111

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:/Users/Admin/PycharmProjects/untitled1/qw.py", line 11, in <module>
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
cv2.error: C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\color.cpp:11111: error: (-215) scn == 3 || scn == 4 in function cv::cvtColor

Comment: As you say that you can see the camera's light ON when you run the program, VideoCapture(0) is accessing the right camera only. By default, the auto exposure will be ON, but try setting it in code. I was getting plain black images because of that once!

Comment: Try increasing the `cv2.waitKey()` parameter to 30. I have had problems with that in the past - on a Mac though, but try anyway.

Comment: @MK62665 I tried to set the auto exposure in my code, but no changes in the image occurred set next:  cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_AUTO_EXPOSURE, 0)
cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_EXPOSURE, -7.0)

Comment: @MarkSetchell I tried, but no results

Comment: Maybe try `normalize()` to range 0..255 with `NORM_MINMAX` before display.

Comment: @Romka_10101 When you set exposure,  use 'cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_EXPOSURE, value)'. Also, can you try '-4.5' for exposure value? To switch on/off auto exposure, you pass 'True' /'False' respectively in cv2.CAP_PROP_AUTO_EXPOSURE

Comment: @MK62665 I try pass 'False' respectively in cv2.CAP_PROP_AUTO_EXPOSURE and  try '-4.5' for exposure value, but nothing

Comment: Debugged - code works just fine using Dyna-lite USB cam. Got life-stream with grey image output.. Python 2.7.14, OpenCV3.2.0.

Comment: @MarkSetchell try cv2.normalize(gray, None, 0, 255, cv2.NORM_MINMAX) ,but then I get a black image

Comment: If you want a real cam with sdk for python then check my SO answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48866976/8928024).

Comment: @ZF007 You say that need to use another camera(like Dyna-lite USB cam)? or what?

Comment: Its a complicated story behind cheap cams (price range 40-200 bucks is cheap) and getting access to their sdk libraries... for the latter you pay coins one way or the other. Dyna-lite has rather low-pricing (aggressive style for entering market) so they made their default libs easy access. They are high-end of the low-pricing range. FLIR has acquired GreyPoint who has cams in all ranges and ... those well-appreciated wrapper. Make cost analysis..20 hours spending on getting genius fixed or ... buy one you can even use as microscope and show dust in keyboards?

Comment: it even could be your genius has faulty firmware but I saw the website didn't offer upgrades or software (not logged in.. might prevent showing that, not sure). My type of cams cost 700-1400 a pop.. good for machine vision and have high framerates ;p And apparently opencv has no access to life-stream in your device. You might want to check with default taking pics..if that works at all.

Comment: @ZF007 Thanks for the advice)

Comment: ... NP, your welcome, by-the-way, in the previous comment I meant: taking picture with provided genius software. I wasn't clear about that, my bad. Also, see if you can remove all cam software/drives, including from regedit and then reinstall after cold-boot. Might be that genius software sees OpenCV and thinks... lets shove a lib file there so it works. .. You never know with those Easter eggs (like playing Tetris in excel;p)

Answer (score 0):

Another beating around the bush with your cam can be done with below debugging code. The exceptionhook should spam error code back you normally won't see if the script hits a roadblock and terminates silently. I use that in editors.

```
import sys, cv2, time


def my_exception_hook(exctype, value, traceback):
    # Print the error and traceback
    print(exctype, value, traceback)
    # Call the normal Exception hook after
    sys._excepthook(exctype, value, traceback)
    sys.exit(1)

def runcam():

    camera = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

    for i in range(10):
        time.sleep(1)  # implemented for cams with long image aquisition time. Its 1 sec.
                       # delay before the next step is repeated until range has finished.
                       # From first image to last each image becomes brighter.
        return_value, image = camera.read()
        cv2.imwrite('opencv'+str(i)+'.png', image)
        print ' taking image %s' % (i+1)


    del(camera)

    # Back up the reference to the exceptionhook
    sys._excepthook = sys.excepthook

    # Set the exception hook to our wrapping function
    sys.excepthook = my_exception_hook

def check_cam_index():
    i = 0
    found = False
    for i in range(4):
            capture = cv2.VideoCapture(i)
            if not capture:
                print "UNABLE TO CAPTURE CAMERA"
            else:
                found = True
                print "taken camera from index: ", i
                break

    if found == False:
        print "!!! No camera was found."
        sys.exit()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    check_cam_index()
    runcam()
```

Comment: try [here at onlinemirror](http://www.youronlinemirror.com/) to see if the cam remotely works.

Comment: good.. then try the testcam I've just added to the answer. This will tell where your cam (i) is located for OpenCV: `capture = cv2.VideoCapture(i)`. The index-value then can be checked with the one on your code. It might be that you're unknowingly use the wrong index-value for the cam. If so you should see `libpng warning: Image width is zero in IHDR
libpng warning: Image height is zero in IHDR
libpng error: Invalid IHDR data`

Comment: I get 'taken camera from index:  0'

Comment: Lets use that then. implemtent pause code of 1 sec behind `print ' taking image %s' % (i+1)`. And... turn on a lamp on your room.

Comment: ....then its your cam-drivers not compatible with OpenCV. As last resort you can (re)compile all OpenCV or reinstall Camera software or drivers... but there is a huge change your cam is not suitable for OpenCV. Anyway.. I'm out of options aside of the ones above given about another cam. May wanna try logitec webcam in the store if Python/OpenCV is on laptop......